# Detect keyup event of contenteditable child whose parent is a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

**Goal:** Attach a keydown event handler to a contenteditable span that is the child of a contenteditable div.

**Problem:** If you type in the span the parent event is triggered not the childs. What I want is the child to trigger so I can grab the text. I only want THAT contenteditable child as there will be many.

HTML/JS is below and the fiddle link is here: http://jsfiddle.net/aBYpt/4/

---

### HTML

```
<div class="parent" contenteditable="true">
    Parent div text.

    <span class="child" contenteditable="true">First child span text.</span>
    <span class="child" contenteditable="true">Second child span text.</span>
    <span class="child" contenteditable="true">Third child span text.</span>
</div>

<div id="console"></div>
```

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(document).on( 'keyup', '.parent', function() {
    $('#console').html( 'Parent keyup event fired.' );
    //do stuff
});

$(document).on( 'keyup', '.child', function() {
    $('#console').html( 'Child keyup event fired.' );
    //do stuff
});
```

**Note: Event handling is delegated to document because elements are dynamically added.

Comment: review this (may be what you're after): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164213/how-to-stop-event-bubbling-on-checkbox-click

Comment: I just found this one which I think is more relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072164/keypress-event-on-nested-content-editable-jquery , seems like a hack tho... I think this is a bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So this is a bug. Workaround confirmed for FF23 and CHROME29 (on linux with no vm so can't test IE). You *must* set the wrapping spans as contenteditable false, you can't just omit declaring the contenteditable attribute, which is rediculous. Solution via [Keypress event on nested content editable (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072164/keypress-event-on-nested-content-editable-jquery)

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aBYpt/14/

### HTML

```
<div class="parent" contenteditable="true">
    Parent div text.

    <span contenteditable="false">
        <span class="child" contenteditable="true">First child span text.</span>
    <span contenteditable="false">
        <span class="child" contenteditable="true">Second child span text.</span>
    </span>
</div>

<div id="console"></div>
```

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(document).on( 'keyup', '.parent', function() {
    //do stuff
    $('#console').html( 'Parent keyup event fired.' );
});

$(document).on( 'keyup', '.child', function(e) {
    //do stuff
    $('#console').html( 'Child keyup event fired.' );
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I disagree that this is a bug: key events are only fired on elements capable of receiving the focus, which includes inputs and contenteditable elements. Elements within a contenteditable element don't qualify. You can infer the element containing the caret from the browser's selection object anyway.

Comment: It's not a non sequitur. I admit I didn't define my terms in great detail (like this [definition of "editing host"](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#editing-host), which is what I was getting at), but I hoped my point was clear. Elements that can receive focus can fire key events. Elements that are inside a contenteditable element **without any elements with contenteditable="false"** in between cannot receive focus, therefore do not generate key events.

Comment: There is text selection issue with this answer. I could not select the parent and child text continuously.