# Jquery keypress not working

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have newly created table
and I want to bind key-press event to td

I have written the following code and it is not working

```
$("body").on("keypress",".control table tr td",function(e){
    alert(9);
});
```

and I replaced keypress with click then it is working

```
$("body").on("click",".control table tr td",function(e){
    alert(9);
});
```

Comment: How can you `keypress` on `td`? And you didn't ask any question.

Comment: Why would you want to `keypress` on td????

Comment: Random objects cannot have a keypress event.  Only elements that can have focus can have keypress.  You need to use `$("body").keypress`.

Comment: Basically a "keypress" event is when the browser senses a keyboard input.I think you misunderstood between keypress and click which is an event that gets fired when you press the mouse button.

Comment: I have <div class="editor" contentEditable="true">
                
                </div> and created table with in this div, means this is run tim editable

Comment: You still have to have some element (`input`, `textarea` etc) focused to fire a keypress

Comment: any alternative? @KaarelKont-Kontson

Comment: As written in my answer, it is actually possible to add `onkeypress` to a `td`: [W3C link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp). Some research helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18772205/1225621) you might need to set the parenting element's `contentEditable="false"` (not sure about your document structure, but maybe `tr`?). You might also try setting the `contentEditable` explicitly for the `td` element.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as written in [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp), onkeypress event can occur on **every HTML element**, but not `<base>`, `<bdo>`, `<br>`, `<head>`, `<html>`, `<iframe>`, `<meta>`, `<param>`, `<script>`, `<style>`, and `<title>`.

You still need to have focusable tag. So, in order to do that to a `td`, you have to use [`tabindex`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.tabindex) attribute.

Based on those two links, you can do something like this:

```
<!-- this is td that needs to be focused in order to get onkeypress event -->
<td tabindex="1"></td>
```