# Detect jquery events on contenteditable divs inside of mustache template

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, mustache

**Goal:** Attach an event handler to a contenteditable div that's nested inside a mustache template/script.

**Problem:** I have a mustache js template that I want to be editable. The idea is that on keyup it should trigger an event (for use later to update the same data server-side).

The block is editable, but contenteditable events don't fire inside the script tag.

I tried more general tips like: 
[Detect keyup event of contenteditable child whose parent is a contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771651/detect-keyup-event-of-contenteditable-child-whose-parent-is-a-contenteditable-di)
and 
[Keypress event on nested content editable (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072164/keypress-event-on-nested-content-editable-jquery)
but none deal with the templating scenario.

---

**HTML**

```
<script id="post" type="text/template">
    <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">  
        <h2>{{bio}}</h2>
        <p>{{summary}}</p>
    </div>

    <span class="child" contenteditable="true">static inside template.</span>

</script>
```

**JQuery**

```
  $('.editable').on('keyup', function() {
      alert('editable changed')
  });

  $('.child').on('click', function() {
    alert('static child changed')
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bind events to a parent that exists in the dom at the time of binding (delegate)

```
$(document.body).on('keyup','.editable', function() {
  alert('editable changed')
  })
 .on('click','.child', function() {
    alert('static child changed')
  });
```