# Attaching keypress and focusout event to elements inside contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I want to attach `keypress` and `focusout` event handlers to a paragraph inside contenteditable `div`.

The following code doesn't seem to work:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p id="p1">Test</p>
    <p id="p2">Test</p>
    <p id="p3">Test</p>
</div>

$('#p1').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    alert('keypress');
});

$('#p1').focusout(function(e) {
    alert('focusout');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THPmr/174/)

Comment: yes, Regent beat me to it! Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2r8qy7bL/

Comment: I want to attach event to paragraph and not to div. There will be multiple paragraph and I want to monitor changes in paragraph with id p1

Comment: @mundella you can want it, but due to `contenteditable="true"` you won't be able to do this. Use several `<div id="pX" contenteditable="true">Test</div>` instead.

Comment: @Regent next time dont hurry to put the solution. "you won't be able to do this" these words do not belong to stackoverflow :)

Comment: @mundella once again: you can't make _keypress and focusout event handlers to a paragraph inside contenteditable div_ to work. The solution with range, that Roko C. Buljan has suggested, works with event handler, binded to `<div>` (_basically the contenteditable is the one that will respond to events_), not to `<p>`. This is all about formulation of your question.

Comment: Exactly..so shifting ids is not a solution dude!

Comment: @mundella you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072164/keypress-event-on-nested-content-editable-jquery) for solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the `contenteditable` is the one that will respond to events dispatched from the inner Nodes. If we get the caret position and than target it's range's parentNode - than we can retrieve the desired ID

```js
$('[contenteditable]').on('keypress focusout', function(ev) {
  var node = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
  var nodeParent = node.parentNode;
  
  // Do something if parent node ID is "p1"
  if( nodeParent.id === "p1") {
    console.log( nodeParent.id +' '+ ev.type ); // or whatever you need to do here
  }
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
   <p id="p1">TestP1 do someting on keypress</p>
   <p id="p2">TestP2 is Not Interesting</p>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: perfect..except the typo in `console`. Tested in chrome and serves my purpose. JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/THPmr/183/

Comment: great solution! better than many similar, existing and highly upvoted one's in SO!!

Answer (score 1):

There's an answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18772205/2100255

Basically, you need to wrap your inner contenteditables with non-contenteditables. The event fires off the node which declares contenteditable=true.

Answer (score -2):

I have altered the solution, Refer the latest [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THPmr/179/)

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#p1[contenteditable="true"]', function(e) {
   alert("test");
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/THPmr/173/ Any way probably the OP wants to target exactly and only that poor `#p1` that's inside the contenteditable DIV

Comment: I want to attach event to paragraph and not to div. There will be multiple paragraph and I want to monitor changes in paragraph with id p1

Comment: @mundella you didn't mention it from the beginning, and now this answer gets downvotes. It's not good at all.

Comment: It was very clear what I wanted to achieve as the id was always on paragraph. Shifting the ids is not a solution.

Comment: @mundella - No, you have appended the additional <p> tags in the recent edit. Anyhow I will try to resolve this.

Comment: @ManoNamo with moving `contenteditable="true"` to `<p>` you can stay JS code "as is", without this way to add event handler (`$(document).on('keypress', '#p1[contenteditable="true"]',`).

Answer (score -2):

You can do it as below
Instead of click event you can change it to event on which you want to track the change.I am using click for example

```js
$("div").click(function(e){
    console.log($("#"+$(e.target)[0].id).text());
});
```

Comment: Its similar as binding event on paragraph.

Comment: I think rather bind multiple event on every <p> tag you can bind only event on <div> and get <p> from it and check for further logic you want to add