# keyboard events binding in component within contenteditable

Tags: angular, contenteditable, keyboard-events

I try to listen to keyboard events on a component inside div[contenteditable=true]. why is it not working?

plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/Tjmihqc1r5UrS3XJ3QQ0?p=preview

template:

`<div contenteditable="true"> <h2 (keydown)="log($event)" (keyup)="log($event)" (keypress)="log($event)" (click)="log($event)">Hello {{name}}</h2> </div>`

click - work

keydown,keyup,keypress - not work

UPDATE:
I discovered that the problem does not apply to angular 2
its contenteditable related [Keypress event on nested content editable (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072164/keypress-event-on-nested-content-editable-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div contenteditable="true" (keyup)="onKey($event)"> 
    <h2>Hello {{values}}</h2>
  </div>
  `,
})
```

Inside your component.ts

```
export class App {
  name:string;
  log = [];
  values = '';
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  onKey(event: any) { 
    console.log(event);
    this.values += event.key + ' | ';
  }
}
```

According to the Angular2 documents you need to use Keyup instead of Keydown [Get User input from $event](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html)

[Plunkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/cU2Cy5M9Rfc6FR4bTQ4i?p=preview)

Comment: There is no difference between: keyup, keydown, keypress in my case.
None of this does not work

Comment: @ШлыковСергей just added a plunkr example to my answer.

Comment: its not what i trying to do. goal is to bind to **child** component of contenteditable. not to contenteditable itself.

Comment: Ok so I've updated the answer and the plunkr, based off what you just said.

Comment: i want _event.target_ to be _h2_ not _div_. i can do it with plain javascript by listening keyboard events on h2 element. but, for some reason, I can not repeat it with angular 2 template syntax

Comment: my bad, I was reviewed my code and i cant do it with plain javascript... :/